# MySQL Won't Install on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation

It was working fine before and I was configuring the email server when I restarted the mysql (via /etc/init.d/mysql restart). I'm pretty sure that I did not touch anything in there but I can remember doing a failed apt-get update prior to that.

Now my problem starts when all of a sudden it stops and won't even start. I searched on google and even went far to purging everything and doing a new install. But still it won't let me install mysql properly.

I've tried (after doing a remove --purge):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5
```

and it prompts me for a root passsword, but returns me the following error:

```
Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                                                      

  An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have         
  happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the   
  MySQL server.                                                                                         

  You should check the account's password after the package installation.                               

  Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.
```

and I have the following logs too:

```
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 117879 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
130830 14:13:26 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

this question was having the same issue it solved by uninstalling but before that he tried to set the password that is the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253023/unable-to-set-password-for-the-mysql-root-user) and then he tried to solve it in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7455/discussion-between-green7-and-devendra-verma) maybe when you try to set a password it will be solved , just try

Update: Type the following commands in your terminal in order to make a complete remove for mysql.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Also you need to remove the /var/lib/mysql folder if exist by typing the following command

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Then follow the [official ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html) to install. and don't forget to set your mysql password during installation.

Also see this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/416287/cant-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-12-04-cant-find-messagefile-usr-share-mysql-er) its similar to the error you have got during the installation process.

Comment: I did some uninstalling then install again. I even updated Ubuntu version and still no success.

Comment: i don't get what you mean by password. Are you referring to mysql's root account? If it is, then the answer is no. This error actually occurs upon reinstalling mysql-server on the system. I can't seem to continue installing it since it is bringing me this error.

Comment: Thanks for writing down the details. Unfortunately, I have tried that method multiple times and still the error appears and mysql won't install. The same error as listed on the question appears.

Comment: This seemed to solve my problem, after quite a bit of searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem.
maybe aptitude have some config for package.
I think this problem of interference 
Although, this method is purge command .
try running.

1. check installed mysql package

   > dpkg --get-selections|grep mysql
2. remove

   > apt-get remove --purge [installed package]
   >   apt-get autoremove
   >   apt-get autoclean
   >   aptitude purge [installed package]
   >   aptitude clean
   >   aptitude update
   >   aptitude -f install
   >   aptitude full-upgrade
3. install

   > apt-get install mysql-server